# Python requests library - POST requests takes too long

Tags: python, performance, http, post, request

I have a problem with the python `requests` library. I try to send a simple **POST request to my Keycloak server, to introspect an access token**. I tested in in Postman and CURL and both requests are processed very fast (about 100ms).
But the `requests` library somehow **takes up to 45 seconds** for this single request and I really don't know what causes the issue. In my opinion there seems to be no problem in the request code. And since Postman can handle the same request just fine, I guess there is no server issue as well?
Even with a locally deployed Keycloak server, the request takes way too long.

Any way, here is the code snippet for the request I send. I am processing it inside a django middleware:

```
  import requests
  
  class TokenMiddleware:
    # Initialization here
    ...

    def introspect_token(self, token):
      payload = {
         "token": token,
         "client_id": self.client_id,
         "client_secret": self.client_secret_key,
      }
      headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
      }
      response = requests.request(
         "POST", self.token_introspection_endpoint, data=payload, headers=headers
      )
      response.json()
```

Does anybody have a hint what could be causing the issue here?

UPDATE: The Problem seems to be the development server that comes with django. I deployed my app on a gunicorn server and then the requests to keycloak took way less time.

Comment: Perhaps Django is introducing some overhead somehow.  Try making a small standalone python script to do the post call.

Comment: Even when I run the function standalone in a script, the request takes too long. What I noticed though, if I set the `timeout` for the request, the request finishes after the timeout successfully, for example timeout of 200ms. So the response is available after a few milliseconds but the request still lives?

Answer (score -1):

First, I think you should try run `requests` code just as a script to exclude the Problem of `requests`.

Then, maybe you use `requests` call your server by yourself. If your Django run in dev, just have a thread, then it fail